# create a weighted undirected graph from data.frame in r?

Tags: igraph

I have search similar question before,but still do not solve my question.

I have data frame with three columns,First two columns are 
vertex ,third column is weights.
I want to create a weighted undirected graph,I use code like this

```
graph.data.frame(d =aggdat1, directed = F)
```

but How can I add weights ?
besides ,in my data frame,there are some repeated edges ,like a-b and b-a
,I just need make  "directed = F"?

thank you very much.

Comment: from `?graph.data.frame` anything after the first two columns are treated as edge attributes. you can check this with `edge_attr()`. If you want to remove repeated edges use `simplify()`

Comment: thank you very much